# why email is not sent in Windows server by drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

I am an ASP.net programmer and don't know much about drupal cms.

In my website I have a `registration web page(form)` that sends the `registration form` to a specified email.

Previously it worked properly. but we moved server from `linux` to a `windows server` with `IIS` not `apache`.
now the registration form is not sent to specified email.
whats wrong?
Should I change the sender email address in drupal?? If so how to set password and smtp address?

Comment: sounds like you don't have a mail service installed or configured, maybe the ports are not open. Try to debug it catching the error on the code. Have you checked if mail() returns false? please provide some code or error messages...

Comment: I'm working on a shared host. and no error is showed to me. after completing registration form the successfully message is showed but email is not sent.

Comment: is email service started on server?

Comment: I'm not sure. but I think is has been done. because it is a shared hosting server.

Comment: I second [Andre's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1166092/andre) suggestion. This isn't a Drupal issue, rather an underlying php/MTA issue. SMTP bypasses all that and let's you configure an SMTP for sending email, regardless of platform. (Yes, I've used it successfully under XAMPP) BUT, you didn't ask, you're better off with Ubuntu/CentOS/Arch on VirtualBox than XAMPP for your drupal development. Windows AMP has too many issues to deal with. Unless you like solving the non-POSIX DOS paths issues. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses the outgoing mail server defined in your PHP ini file. If you cannot update/edit this then it may be best to use the [SMTP Authentication Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) Module.

Also see these links:

1. http://drupal.org/node/1229932
2. http://forums.iis.net/t/1164375.aspx/1